# Grep exclude line only if multiple patterns match

Tags: regex, shell, grep, regex-negation

I want to find lines that do not contain both `"path": "/"` and `"User-Agent": "curl`. Lines that contain only one of those should be included.

In other words, how can I exclude a line only if it matches multiple patterns?

Comment: Does a matching line have to contain **one** of those patterns, or is "not both" the sole requirement?  Also, did you really mean to leave the closing quote off of `"curl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These double checks in the same line are better done with `awk`:

```
awk '! (/"path": "\/"/ && /"User-Agent": "curl/)' file
```

This uses the logic `awk '! (condition1 && condition2)'`, so it will just fail whenever both strings are found.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
"path": "/" and "User-Agent": "curl
"path": "/" hello
bye "User-Agent": "curl
this is a test
$ awk '! (/"path": "\/"/ && /"User-Agent": "curl/)' a
"path": "/" hello
bye "User-Agent": "curl
this is a test
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use | in a grep command to signal "or", and you can use the -v argument to

so:

```
grep -v \"path\"\:\ \"/\"\\\|curl
```

would print every line that does not include "path": "/" or curl.

Answer (score 0):

This awk should do the job:

```
awk '(/"path": "\/"/ && !/"User-Agent": "curl/) || 
     (!/"path": "\/"/ && /"User-Agent": "curl/)
     {print FILENAME ":" $0}' *
```

This goes by this approach:

```
awk '(/match1/ && !/match2/) || (!/match1/ && /match2/)' *
```

so in other words print if any of the 2 words match but not when both match.